# Are there any Bluetooth Low Energy ( BLE ) libraries for react native?

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am newbie in react native based app development. We have to develop a mobile app (as BLE client) that needs to communicate through BLE (Bluetooth low energy / smart Bluetooth) to monitor an IOT device (a BLE peripheral/central).  We are using Bluetooth Developer studio tool from Bluetooth SIG to design custom BLE services and generate the BLE profile for our IOT device. For the mobile side, we are going to use facebook's react native cross platform framework.

Can anybody recommend some good BLE libraries for react native apps ?

Answer (score 18):

As i couldn't find any good answer at one place so i tried few libraries by myself. I just share my conclusion which may be helpful to other newbies for starting react native based BLE client mobile app.

So, Here are some good BLE libraries for Client(Central) role that can be used in React Native Mobile Apps :-

1. [**react-native-ble-manager**](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=react-native-ble-manager) :
   A great module/library for **low level** BLE communication via service and characteristic UUIDs (i.e BLE commands as hex values )  It's easy to use, widely used by community and well matured library but requires BLE service and characteristic UUIDs knowledge.
2. [**react-native-ble-plx**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ble-plx) Developers who love ReactiveX programming may refer to this Low level BLE communication module via service and characteristic UUIDs (i.e BLE commands as hex values )  It's a very stable library, actively maintained, asynchronous in nature but requires lots of memory and comparatively slow performance due to multiple dependent libraries and usage of base64 encoding/decoding for data conversion.
3. [**react-native-ble-quick-sdk**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ble-quick-sdk) Developers who love Bluetooth Developer Studio and who wants to build app quickly without much BLE knowledge may refer to this **high level** BLE API module which doesn't require knowledge of service and characteristic UUIDs (i.e BLE commands as hex values )  It requires comparatively less memory and gives better performance as it is not using base64 for data conversion. Partially reactive in nature as it use Node's EventEmitter. It auto generates lots of API source for target BLE device and also auto generates device specific sample app. The biggest drawback is that there's no stable version and not widely used yet.
4. [**react-native-ble**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ble) : 
   A NodeJS style low level BLE communication module via service and characteristic UUIDs (i.e BLE commands as hex values ) Not so actively maintained but it's based on a very stable [noble](https://www.npmjs.com/package/noble) library.

Comment: any library with support for peripheral mode? These are all well and good in central mode

Comment: In my experience, react-native-ble-manager takes too much time to scan for devices. Dont know if this is expected behaviour or what. You have any suggestions?

Comment: any of those libraries allow you to advertise (I mean that other devices will be able to discover your device)? I tried with react-native-ble-manager but its not possible to do that

Answer (score 3):

In react native the best library which i have used is below. You can test it. Whether your all requirements are full-filed or not. Even there will be some situations where you will need to manipulate Android Default Bluetooth functionality.

https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx

The best way to resolve your problem is try to understand Bluetooth functionality of Android and IOS and how you can manipulate nicely to work with above library.

Comment: Thanks @hemant-nagarkoti for the answer. I tried this package but it is too heavy. It uses reactive paradigm. I am looking for non reactive library which is light weight and easy to debug in XCode. Reactive programming based libraries are generally difficult to debug.